# Why is my else statement not working for Cardview with two functions?

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick, android-button, android-cardview

I have a CardView that works as a Start/Stop function.

Start, when pressed, works. However Stop will not work. I know that the onClick event is working as the text view changes, however the actual function does not work. Any help greatly appreciated. I will post whole code below.

```
 //Defining Cards on Landing Page
    appsCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.apps_card);
    parentalControlsCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.parentalControls_id);
    customSettingsCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.customSettings);
    activateCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.activate_id);
    StartStopCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.StartStopCard);


    //Add OnClick Listeners
    appsCard.setOnClickListener(this);
    parentalControlsCard.setOnClickListener(this);
    customSettingsCard.setOnClickListener(this);
    activateCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ruleSets.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(LandingPage.this, "You did not create a custom setting.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                PendingIntent pending_start;
                PendingIntent pending_stop;
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(LandingPage.this, LockOptionReceiver.class);
                Intent stopIntent = new Intent(LandingPage.this, LockOptionReceiver.class);
                Calendar startTime = new GregorianCalendar();
                Calendar endTime = new GregorianCalendar();
                String startString = ruleSets.get(0).getStartTime();
                String endString = ruleSets.get(0).getEndTime();

                String[] startArr = startString.split(":");
                String[] endArr = endString.split(":");

                startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(startArr[0]));
                startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(startArr[1]));

                endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(endArr[0]));
                endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(endArr[1]));

                pending_start = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LandingPage.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                pending_stop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LandingPage.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                startIntent.putExtra("status", "start");
                stopIntent.putExtra("status", "stop");

                Toast.makeText(LandingPage.this, "Your ruleset will start at " + startString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                setStatus("Lock Active");
                setProcess("Stop");

                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, startTime.getTimeInMillis(), pending_start);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, startTime.getTimeInMillis(), pending_stop);
            }
        }
    });


    CardView StartStopCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.StartStopCard);
    StartStopCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        mStarted = !mStarted;
            if (mStarted) {
                mStarted=false;
                SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
                editor.remove("switcher");
                editor.remove("switcher2");
                editor.remove("lockStatus");
                editor.remove("processStatus");
                editor.commit();
                editor.putString("switcher", "true");
                editor.putString("switcher2", "true");
                editor.putString("lockStatus", "Lock Active");
                editor.putString("processStatus", "Start");
                editor.apply();
                intent.putExtra("status", "start");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                intent.putExtra("processStatus", "start");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                String status = setting.getString("lockStatus", "");
                setStatus(status);
                String processStatus = setting.getString("processStatus" , "");
                setProcess(processStatus);

            }
            else {
                mStarted= true;
                SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
                editor.remove("switcher");
                editor.remove("switcher2");
                editor.remove("lockStatus");
                editor.remove("processStatus");
                editor.commit();
                editor.putString("switcher", "false");
                editor.putString("switcher2", "false");
                editor.putString("lockStatus", "Lock Deactivated");
                editor.putString("processStatus", "Stop");
                editor.apply();
                intent.putExtra("status", "stop");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                intent.putExtra("processStatus", "start");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                String status = setting.getString("lockStatus", "");
                setStatus(status);
                String processStatus = setting.getString("processStatus" , "");
                setProcess(processStatus);

            }
        }

    });

}
```

...............................................................................

Comment: remove this line "mStarted = !mStarted;" because of this only one statment will work in you onClick. Or remove this mStarted=false; and mStarted= true; in if else blocks

Comment: what do you mean that the text changes so you know the onclick is working?  What function isn't working?

Comment: @TomD the text in the card view changes from Start to Stop. The function of actually stopping the process! It is a program that stops apps from being accessed on an android device. Right now, when the CardView is clicked, the process can begin and lock the apps, however they cannot be unlocked.

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in here

```
 mStarted = !mStarted;
        if (mStarted) {
            mStarted=false;
            ...
        else{
            mStarted = true;
        ...
        }
```

Let's say your `mStarted` starts in `true`. It is reverted before the if statement and then turned to `true` again, because it goes to **else**. When you press the button it will do the same thing, it will get reverted and go to the same else. The same if `mStarted` is false from the begining. The point is, it will always go to the same branch.

If you want to toggle the behaviour on clicks (each click goes to a different branch of the if statement) then you either remove `mStarted = !mStarted;` or remove the `mStarted` assignements from the branches.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply I removed this but unfortunately it still did not solve my problem there must be something else too

Comment: which one did you remove?

Comment: Thank you so much sorry I had to debug then it worked.

Comment: Yes thank you :) I am trying to also change the bg color of the cardview within that else statement but StartStopCard.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.card_color)); wont work

Comment: Did you try just doing: StartStopCard.setBackgroundResource(R.color.card_color)

Comment: Yes but get error Variable 'StopStartCard' is accessed from the inner class, needs to be declared final

Comment: Try it like this: view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.card_color)